# Oozie file or archive tags reference file stored in Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, oozie, azure-data-lake

We have custom Apache Hadoop installation on Azure compute nodes and use Apache Oozie to schedule workflows.

All workflow and coordinator xml files are deployed into Microsoft Azure Data Lake external storage.

Currently there is a [pyspark action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.0.0-beta1/DG_SparkActionExtension.html#PySpark_with_Spark_Action), for it we deploy egg file into a different path on Azure Data Lake.

In workflow action I tried to reference it through file tag with no success:

```
<action name='start-job'>
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>${sparkMaster}</master>
            <mode>${sparkMode}</mode>
            <name>PySparkJob</name>
            <jar>${executor}</jar>
            <spark-opts>
                --num-executors ${num_executors} --executor-cores ${executor_cores} --executor-memory ${executor_memory} --driver-memory ${driver_memory} --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=${executor_memory_overhead} --py-files ${egg_file_name} --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=${driver_max_result_size}
            </spark-opts>
            <arg>...</arg>
            <file>${adl_pyfiles_absolute_path}/${egg_file_name}</file>
       </spark>
       <ok to="success-email" />
       <error to="error-email"/>
</action>
```

This results in:

```
Error Message     : Missing py4j and/or pyspark zip files. Please add them to the lib folder or to the Spark sharelib.
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the root cause.

So having just mentioned file as follows is not enough:

```
<file>${adl_pyfiles_absolute_path}/${egg_file_name}</file>
```

for referencing it in the spark-opts `--py-files ${egg_file_name}`.

So giving it explicit name fixes the problem i.e.:

```
<file>${adl_pyfiles_absolute_path}/${egg_file_name}#${egg_file_name}</file>
```